# Sinal de igual na definição de método Ruby

Tags: ruby, método, getters-setters

Me deparei com as seguintes definições de métodos e gostaria de saber a diferença entre a primeira definição e a segunda.

Esta primeira não possui o sinal de igual na definição:

```
def nome
    nome_exibicao(:nome)   
end
```

Já esta segunda possui o sinal de igual:

```
def nome=(novo_nome)
  if !self[:nome_real]
    self[:nome_real] = novo_nome
    gera_nome_exibicao
  else
    if novo_nome.is_a? Hash
      self[:nome] = novo_nome.sort.map { |b| b[1] }.join(' ')
    else
      self[:nome] = novo_nome
    end
  end   
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em resumo, os métodos getter e setter expõem campos da classe. Eles podem expor o campo de maneira crua, como

```
[privado] meu_campo             = 25
[público] get_meu_campo         # retorna 25
[público] set_meu_campo(valor)  # seta meu_campo para valor (parâmetro)
```

ou podem utilizar algum tipo de lógica, como

```
[privado] meu_campo             = 25
[público] get_meu_campo         # retorna 25 * 2
[público] set_meu_campo(valor)  # seta meu_campo para valor/2 (parâmetro)
```

> Se ainda não entendeu o que são getters e setters não
>   resposta agora. Entenda o que são pelos links abaixo e continue a leitura.
>
> - [Get e Set - Métodos Acessores em Java](https://www.devmedia.com.br/get-e-set-metodos-acessores-em-java/29241) (é Java, mas o que serve é o conceito)
> - [What are setters and getters in Ruby?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-setters-and-getters-in-Ruby) (talvez isso responda a pergunta)

Na maioria das linguagens, o padrão de nomenclatura para escrever um getter e um setter é

```
private int propriedade;
public int getPropriedade() { ... }
public void setPropriedade(valor) { ... }
```

Mas em Ruby é diferente

```
@propriedade = 0
def propriedade; end
def propriedade=; end
```

Veja [uma aplicação um pouco mais contextualizada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398980/6241184):

```
class Pessoa < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :nome, :sobrenome

  def nome_completo # getter
    "#{@nome} #{@sobrenome}"
  end

  def nome_completo=(value) # setter
    @nome, @sobrenome = value.split(' ')
  end
end
```

Se você não precisa de nenhuma lógica específica no getter e nem no setter, use o `attr_accessor`. Ou seja:

```
class Carro
  def velocidade # getter
    @velocidade
  end

  def velocidade=(nova_velocidade) # setter
    @velocidade = nova_velocidade
  end
end
```

é a mesma coisa que

```
class Carro
  attr_accessor :velocidade # getter e setter
end
```

Saiba que `attr_accessor` é um atalho para

```
class Carro
  attr_reader :velocidade # getter
  attr_writer :velocidade # setter
end
```

Comment: Excelente resposta. Agora entendi que se trata de um setter normal porém na maneira Ruby de se escrever.

Answer (score 3):

Métodos acessores e modificadores são muito comuns e dão a ideia de propriedades. Existe uma convenção para a definição destes métodos, que a maioria dos desenvolvedores Ruby segue (assim como Java tem a convenção para getters e setters):

```
class Pessoa
  def nome # acessor
    @nome
  end

  def nome=(novo_nome)
    @nome = novo_nome
  end
end
```

**Alguns artigos que lhe podem ser útil:**

- [Atributos e propriedades: acessores e modificadores](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-ruby-on-rails/mais-ruby-classes-objetos-e-metodos/#4-11-atributos-e-propriedades-acessores-e-modificadores)
- [Variável de instância e método de acesso](https://www.devmedia.com.br/orientacao-a-objetos-com-ruby/33726)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.  Mas ainda não saquei bem oq faz o sinal de = ali. Mesmo lendo o link. Poderia explicar de uma forma um pouco mais detalhada?